# Javascript variable assignment of object returns string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run the following code:

```
var status = null;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/status",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        status = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.error(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The interesting part is the following line: `status = data;`

In the debugger I can see that `data` has the value `Object {7100665: 0, 8800798: 0}`. jQuery correctly parses the JSON-string returned from the server into an object.

However, one line later the global variable `status` has the value `"[object Object]"` and behaves like a string object - **string does not have the object assigned to it as expected**.

It looks like there was an implicite `typeof` call in the assignment going on, which cannot be, right? Is there some more going on that I am not aware of? The `Content-Type` of the ajax call is `application/json`.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`status` as a global variable is actually [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.status), which is a (non-standard) host object that lets you manipulate the text of the status bar in browsers that implement it. Its value is assumed to be a string, so any value that you assign to it will be silently coerced into a string.

The real problem is that you're polluting the global scope with variables. Use an IIFE and this will not be an issue:

```
(function() {
    var status = null;
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? If he said `status = null` rather than `var status = null` then he'd be using `window.status` rather than the local `status` variable.

Comment: @muistooshort: If this code is in the global scope, using `var` won't really change anything.

Answer (score 1):

found it... `status` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm).

Comment: That page is bad. E.g. it claims `InnerWidth` is a keyword, which is nonsense.